# How to deal with special characters in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, ascii

I've received a text file in which the text is like this, ãYAHOO.COM. When I'm debugging in Visual Studio, the value I see for the character is "�"c. Firstly can anyone tell what is the character before yahoo. Is it a special character or some html character, and what is the character that I'm seeing in VS while debugging.

So it goes like this, the ascii value of the character turns out to be 63.But when I write the value to a file it generates 3 characters whose ascii values are above 127. Very Weird

How can this be handled in VB.NET

Comment: You need to read **[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the correct encoding when you read the file (the same as was used to write the file). For example, if you read the file using a StreamReader, you might have code like:

```
Dim reader As New StreamReader(myFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

The second parameter represents the encoding. Here we use the default encoding (ANSI). If you've got some unknown or strange characters using this encoding, you can try using a different encoding like `System.Text.Encoding.Utf8` or `System.Text.Encoding.Ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the character. Try getting the ASCII code of the character:

   ```
   Response.Write(Asc(YourString.Substring(0, 1)))
   ```
2. Clean your input string. Create an array arrCh() with all ASCII characters you want to delete and loop through the string with:

   ```
   YourString = YourString.Replace(Chr(arrCh(i)),"")
   ```

Comment: Despite the name, `Asc` hasn’t got a whole lot to do with ASCII – ASCII was last used some 15 years ago. It plays no role in .NET. Your second item sounds like a very bad workaround for not using correct encodings.

Comment: 1) Konrad, correct me if I am wrong. ASC returns a decimal ANSI code of a character, which in turn consists of printable ASCII codes (0-127) and non printable (128-255).

Comment: You are wrong. As I said, ASCII is no longer in use anywhere in .NET (unless you explicitly use it as an encoding). `Asc` and `AscW` both return Unicode code points, since *all* strings in .NET are Unicode. Coincidentally, the first 128 Unicode code points happen to be identical to the first 128 ASCII codes. But describing the return value of `Asc` as ASCII is still wrong. In particular, for any value > 127, the return values are no longer identical. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Ok, I need to understand the difference between ASC and ASCW then. Also, on MSDN if you choose same help but for VS2005 then they write that ASC returns value between 0 and 255 and give a link to ASCII table with char codes as a reference. Check it out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.80).aspx#Y600

Comment: Indeed, the MSDN contains numerous errors that are slowly fixed. You found one such error that has been fixed in a subsequent version.

Comment: Konrad, after you wrote I even checked your profile. Ok, if you are an expert in .NET and strings manipulation, you might then help. I did a practical test. 

First, the reference for ANSI and Unicode codes: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Next, I made a practical test on a character, for which ANSI and Unicode codes are different.


        Dim m As String = ChrW(8220)
        MessageBox.Show(Asc(m))
        MessageBox.Show(AscW(m))

ASC clearly returns ANSI and ASCW - Unicode.

Where was I initially wrong then regarding the ASCII codes?

Comment: First of, ANSI != ASCII. Secondly, both ANSI and ASCII are actually ill-defined (in particular for characters > 127). In particular, different Windows PCs use different ANSI character sets (western PCs use codepage 1252 but East European and Asian PCs use different code pages, and hence `Asc` returns different codes there). Neither of those correspond to an encoding usually called “ASCII” (= either US-ASCII or ISO-8895-1). They are similar but distinct encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Open the textfile in Notepad and then try "save as...". If the file ANSI or UNICODE?

if ANSI, then save a copy as UNICODE and retry with the new file.

Many characters are displayable in Windows from an ANSI file, but Visual basic "refuses" to do so, if you don't explicitly define the file as Unicode (identified by values 255, 254 in the first 2 bytes in the file)